# What env var to send requests to a HAProxy instance?

Tags: proxy, haproxy

I have a HAProxy configured that works as expected when sending requests directly to the proxy host  and port that the proxy is listening on. The proxy is running in TCP mode.

```
frontend tcp-in-mssql
  bind :5650
  mode tcp
  use_backend mssql

backend mssql
  mode tcp
  server mssql01.mydomain.com mssql01.mydomain.com:5650 check
```

When I try to send requests to the proxy by using the SOCKS_PROXY or ALL_PROXY env vars, the proxy isn't used and the connection is made directly.

example:

```
SOCKS_PROXY=socks://localhost:5650 my_command --target=mssql01.mydomain.com:5650
ALL_PROXY=socks://localhost:5650 my_command --target=mssql01.mydomain.com:5650
```

The proxy is bypassed and a TCP connection is made directly to the target host. Though if do something like `my_command --target=localhost:5650` the TCP connection goes through the proxy and is made successfully to the backend target server.

How can I route traffic to the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Socks is a specific protocol to be spoken by client and proxy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS). Socks allows the client to specify which server to connect to on which port. To do so, the client establishes a connection to the socks proxy, the socks proxy then establishes a connection to the server and forwards the traffic from client to server and vice versa.

Example:

```
client -> socks proxy (port: 1080) -> server1 (port: clients choice)
                                   -> server2 (port: clients choice)
                                   -> serverN (port: clients choice)
                                   -> server (clients choice)
```

Your HAProxy configuration configures the haproxy to serve as a reverse proxy for tcp connections on port 5650. Tcp traffic received on port 5650 will then be forwarded to one of the destination servers configured in backend section.

Example:

```
client -> reverse proxy (port 5650) -> backend (server and port 
                                       as defined in haproxy config)
```

So you already have a working solution for proxying the connection to the mssql backend. Just configure the mssql client to connect to the hapoxy on port 5650.

If you need a socks proxy to suit your use case, you have to replace the haproxy with a dedicated, socks capable proxy solution